# Wordpress update_post_meta removes my br tags

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a special case where I've made a few fields in my post that shows like this [image: Backend]

Now it all updates great and it reflects it in the frontend like this:

[image: Frontend]

The problem is that im trying to break the text by inserting a **br** in my text field, but it gets stripped by the update_post_meta.

Is there a way to prevent it from being stripped?

Answer (score 0):

Post meta values are passed through the stripslashes() function that delete any html for security reason. Prefer the use of css to make your text on multiple lines with a max-width, or use an html editor on a textarea for that.

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

Answer (score 0):

I ended up simply doing a string replace and making ## get replaced with `<br>` on my frontend.